# Problem of XMLHttprequest, reponseText still empty

Tags: php, ajax

I create articles on an administration and on each article i have a button to like it, at the onclick, the javascript call the php code in an other file to fill the database, and the database should  resend the number of like, but the echo on the processing file doesn't fill the reponseText of the XMLHttprequest and I don't know why and that's I'am trying to solve and understand.
I succeeded to do it but I don't want to refresh the page at each like, so i use XMLHttpRequest to display correctly the likes whithout refreshing.
I followed serevals tutoriels, but that doesn't work well.I had to miss something.

First I have a file : index.php with my javascript and php code:

```
 <ul class="ulp">
            <li class="lip">
                <button class="likebutton" onclick="like('<?= $ipclient ?>','<?= $event->getID()?>')" style="color:#5B5A57">
                    <i id="coeur<?= $event->getID()?>" class="<?= $classlike ?>">
                        <span id="nblike<?= $event->getID()?>"> 
                            <?= $tableLikes->countLike($event->getID()) ?>
                        </span>
                    </i>
                </button>
            </li>
      </ul>

  <script>
    function like(ipclient,eventid)
    {
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
            document.getElementById("nblike" +eventid).innerHTML = this.responseText;

};
        xhttp.open("GET","event/" + ipclient + "-" + eventid, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

When I am cliking on this button that send correctly the request.
I have a second file that processes the data:

```
<?php
use App\Model\Likes;
use App\Table\LikesTable;
use App\Connection;

$pdo = Connection::getPDO();

$like = new Likes();
$tableLike = new LikesTable($pdo);

$ip = $params['ip'];
$id_event = $params['id'];

if($tableLike->likeIp($ip,$id_event) === true){

    $like->setId_article($id_event);
    $like->setIp($ip);
    $tableLike->newLike($like);

}else if($tableLike->likeIp($ip,$id_event) === false){
    $tableLike->dislike($ip,$id_event);
    
}
echo $tableLike->countLike($id_event);
```

I would like to have the content of the last echo in the reponseText of my object XMLHttpRequest.
How can I do ?
Thanks you in advance .

Comment: Start by checking what actual response was returned in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: I did:console.log(this) and inside the xhttp.reponseText still empty

Comment: Then do what I actually asked you to do next, please. And if _that_ also shows that the response is empty - well then your server-side script didn’t actually send any, so you need to debug what is going wrong there.

Comment: This is a simple GET request, so you can easily execute it by copy&pasting the URL directly into the browser address bar as well - do you get the desired response then? If not, then clearly your server-side script is at fault.

Comment: I copied the URL into the browser and the echo returned nothing either and it may matter what I put in the echo nothing is returned

Comment: Well then at least you know now, that the problem is likely not in the client-side AJAX part, but in your server-side script. So you will need to do some actual, proper debugging of that part first of all then.

Comment: I'm not sure because at the start of setting up the script I left a header that redirected to this same page, and so it sent me a whole html page in the responseText, but when I echo noting is return. And that's the same result if I echo a simple string like instead of my variable

Comment: And I use a debug page(Whoops) which reports errors to me and in the console there was no error 500 either. But that I don't succed to understand it's why when I put the GET request in the browser URL and the script echo something nothing appeard on the page

Comment: Well then _you_ need to do some proper debugging here, we can not do that for you, we only know a portion of the whole code involved, and don’t have access to your system.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem, it's because I use a router (Altorouter) to redirect the urls, and as my route in GET does not need a layout I put an empty layout on this type of page and therefore the content was not displayed.
Thank you for taking the time to answer me.